# Make div stretch to length of it's content and beyond if parent div is longer?

Tags: css, html, height

I want to make a div (my sidebar) stretch to the bottom of the page. I know that I need to add "height: 100%;" in order to do that.

But when I add height: 100%;, pages that have less content than the sidebar cuts the sidebar's height and then you can't see the sidebar content.

[This is the index page](http://www.tarawilder.com/staging) . Everything looks exactly the way I want it to.

[This is a sample page](http://www.tarawilder.com/staging/?page_id=19) . Notice that the sidebar has been cut.

CSS:

```
#menu-container {
    background-image: url('floral.png');
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute;
}

#menu {
    background-image: url('menubg.png');
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    height: 100%; 
}

#content {
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 325px;
    width: 1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

*** @Ritabrata Gautam ***

The changed CSS fixed my second problem but now I'm back to the cut off sidebar on shorter pages: See here: http://www.tarawilder.com/staging/?page_id=19

I'm leaving my house now, I'll be able to respond later tonight. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#container {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 900px;
}
```

try this..it will give you the result you want..though there are many other mistakes in your html markup

some other areas where you need to be careful...

your container's width is 900px..which contains side menu and the large text...combined width of your side menu and the large text is far greater than your 900px width of your container..as you are not using `overflow:hidden;` you cant see the effect...why dont you apply `overflow:auto; width:100%` or something like that

**BETTER CSS::**

```
#container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
}
```

**ACCORDING TO YOUR NEW PROBLEM** :: now your body height must be more than 100% now..thats why after 100% height your side menu becomes invisible

**CHANGED CSS ::**

```
#container {
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

**your third problem ::**
strange...you are now using `width:100%` for your cantainer..and your container contains side menu and large text...and side menu has width of 300px and then your having width of 1000px for large text..so naturally the overflowed part ot the text gets invisible; and also remove position:absolute; from container
now your css

```
 #container {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #content {
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 325px;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
```

NOTE:: don't delete your edited part of your question..you have already deleted the 2nd edit you made to your question earlier...it will create difficulties for future users to relate the answer with question

Comment: What are the mistakes? 

And thanks, I forgot to add height: 100% to my container and that seemed to do the trick! Thanks :)

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` rule isn't needed - absolutely positioning an element automatically makes it block-level.

Comment: and also watch what @Adrift said

Comment: Thanks Adrift! I'll fix that.

@Ritabrata Guatam: I took out the 900px. You're right, that was significantly shorter than the actual size of the website. I applied your suggestions. Thanks.

I do have a followup question about my original post: Now if I look at my sidebar, it's not showing the entirety of the content. I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: please report us your new changes and problems with codes and link..and also watch my edit

Comment: I've edited my original question. Changes and current css is under *New Problem* in my question

Comment: can u send us the link showing your problem with new changes..because its working here fine(chrome)

Comment: Same links: http://www.tarawilder.com/staging/

I'm also using Chrome. Just cleared my cache and everything and it's still there. See where it cuts off at "August 2013"? There is supposed to be more content after that. Edit: I have to leave soon. I'll check for your response when I get home. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your parent containers (#container, body, html) are height:100%; as well.

Personally, I would do something like this(if the rest of the site layout allows it):

Instead of creating separate backgrounds for #menu, #menu-caontainer and body i would create background on body something like this: http://cl.ly/image/3L060f2w3Z0s
that would repeat vertically on y axis, so no matter how high the body is the background would stretch/repeat to the bottom.

Comment: I had body and html as height: 100%; but I didn't put it in my container! That seemed to do the trick! Thanks so much!